# R how to subtract vector elements

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a numeric vector/array as below. After sorting in decreasing order, I want to have an array of differences between consecutive elements: I want to subtract 2nd element from 1st, 3rd element from nd etc...I can have n number of elements...how can I achieve the same?

array of difference will have n-1 elements

```
a=c(2,3,5)
a=sort(a,decreasing = TRUE)
```

In the above case array of differences will be (2,1)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the `diff` function. Most simply, apply the absolute value with `abs` (or just multiply by -1) to get the desired result from your  sorted vector.

You could use any of these methods:

```
> a <- c(5, 3, 2)
> -1*diff(a)
# [1] 2 1
> abs(diff(a))
# [1] 2 1
> rev(diff(rev(a)))
# [1] 2 1
```

Comment: Or (if you into being very original) `a[-length(a)] - a[-1]`